# Did the Predators, Yautja, develop the technology they use?

Tags: predator, predator-series

Humans lost many of their predator physical features as they developed and relied upon technology. I was thinking that the Yautja would have lost their fangs in a similar fashion, and long ago in their evolution, being they have spaceships and other highly-advanced technology.

This leads me to wonder whether or not they actually developed the technology themselves or not. If not, how and where did they acquire their technology?

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate questions; **Did the Yautja develop their own tech?** and **Why are an advanced species like the Yautja still so predatory"**

Comment: @Valorum Isn't it reasonable to read the question as being **Did the Yautja develop their own tech** (the question in the title)? The point about fangs simply seems to be an explanation of why the question is being asked.

Comment: “Humans lost many of their predator features as they developed technology.” Er. Citation needed? “I was thinking that the Yautja would have lost their fangs and such long ago” Maybe they used to have even *more* fangs.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think that's pretty much a known fact. If nothing else, the invention of fire and cooking techniques affected our mouths, teeth, and digestive tract.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Humans have lost most of their predatory instincts and features(we are slimmer and more fragile yet more agile and lightweight), you don't see people mistrusting and attacking on site if someone new is on their territory, we don't hunt to impress the weak and the women anymore, we don't kill the weak for the sake of a strong pack, and we certainly don't have duels for leadership(such a shame).

Comment: @Blackwood - The issue here is that the question title and body don't agree. That makes it unclear what question he'd like answered.

Comment: @Valorum -The title is continued by the body, they go like "did the Yautja develop the tech they use? Because 'umies lost many ....."

Comment: @Valorum It seems to me that the title is basically "Did the Yautja develop their own tech" and the question in the body is "If not how did they acquire it".

Comment: @Blackwood - Indeed, and **on its own** that would make an excellent (albeit unanswerable) question. The other question would also make a good stand-alone question.

Comment: Omg... I've been really enjoying reading this site, but this is crazy. Want me to just delete it? You could have answered 5 questions by now, lol

Comment: Maybe none of the guys commenting(including me) have the answer to your question, we're discussing question ethics. Keep your question open and wait for someone with knowledge to answer.

Comment: Human ancestors never really had anatomical "predator features" in the classic sense (claws, carnassial or shark/crocodile type teeth, etc.) to lose - apes don't either, even though they're non-technological. @Balin son of Fundin: actually, humans' slimmer build is fairly likely to be a hunting adaptation ('persistence hunting' by chasing animals to exhaustion, before bows etc were invented).

Comment: @cometaryorbit - We don't have the strength and thinking of our ancestors, most humans are frail and don't resist to damage that the prey might do. We might outrun(considering athletes) our prey to a point of break and catch it, but it won't say "damn man, you got me, have a rib", it will fight, and with no strength we'd lose. The potential is still there, but it won't come in 10-15 years (which is long enough).

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin: surprisingly, it doesn't work that way. Some humans used persistence hunting in recent historical times (later 20th century at least) and maybe still do. Now, modern people who live a relatively sedentary lifestyle don't develop those abilities -- but human anatomy hasn't meaningfully changed since the Paleolithic.

Comment: I thought the title and body were quite clear - did the Yautja develop their own tech and if not, where did they get it? Although the pedantic could argue that this is 2 questions, just asking "Did they develop their own tech" could lead to yes/no answers and the OP would then have to ask another question.

Comment: @cometaryorbit - We as humans rely more on tools these days than in the past, some used persistence and some might still do (those who choose to live in this scenario). But humanity as a group (all races and from everywhere) can't and won't go down to the downright brutal methods of physical and psychological torture that our prey receives(as humans rely on the fear and confusion of the prey to get it). I would like to talk more to you on this subject, if you want and it doesn't bother you, but on another long lasting chat platform, this is off-topic from us.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin: “you don't see people mistrusting and attacking on site if someone new is on their territory”. I do! I’m from Croydon.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's has to be hard to live in a 1st world country. It is more or less in every country that the ones from the bottom attack others, but don't blame the poor beings, they aren't that ... smart.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin: I wasn’t blaming anyone for anything, but yikes, that’s a bunch of assumptions in just a few words.